# Accessing an S3 file from a node_module

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3

I am using the word2vec npm module. This library parses a `.bin` file into a Word2Vec model. To parse the file, we need to call a `load` function with the path of the `.bin` file as a parameter.

Here comes my issue. I have my `.bin` file on an S3 bucket. Retrieving the file with the `s3.getObject()` method leaves me with the data of the file as a buffer, which I can't inject into the word2vec module.

The only solution I see for now is to dive into the module code to make it able to take the raw data as an argument. I am looking for an alternative to this unattractive idea.

Comment: Why don't you save the buffer data in a temp location and point that file to `word2vec` module?

Comment: Thanks ! It did not cross my mind